# Spring Session JDBCTokenRepository override default table

Tags: java, spring, session

Im setting up Spring's session "Remember me" option and using JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl as PersistentTokenRepository for Spring Session. Unfortunately the developers hard-coded the name of table "persistent_logins" which is not suitable for my app and not working in Oracle (because it needs to specify a schema name into SQL query).

**The question is:** which is the easiest way for overriding default table name "persistent_logins" to another?

After doing some search here I figured out that overriding JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl might be an option. But overriding just SQL strings (see the code below) its not working unfortunately.

**Update:**
So I grabbed original source code from here: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.java
Now It works, but I'm doubt whether it's an optimal solution because any changes in original library can brake my code.

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentRememberMeToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;

/**
Overriding standart Spring's JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl to implement custom table instead of default
 */
public class JdbcTokenRepositoryImplCust extends JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl implements PersistentTokenRepository {
    // ~ Static fields/initializers
    // =====================================================================================

    public static final String DEF_TABLE_SQL = "sb_tst.plan_user_logins";
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "create table " + DEF_TABLE_SQL + " (username varchar(64) not null, series varchar(64) primary key, "
            + "token varchar(64) not null, last_used timestamp not null)";
    public static final String DEF_TOKEN_BY_SERIES_SQL = "select username,series,token,last_used from "+ DEF_TABLE_SQL +" where series = ?";
    public static final String DEF_INSERT_TOKEN_SQL = "insert into " + DEF_TABLE_SQL + "(username, series, token, last_used) values(?,?,?,?)";
    public static final String DEF_UPDATE_TOKEN_SQL = "update " + DEF_TABLE_SQL + " set token = ?, last_used = ? where series = ?";
    public static final String DEF_REMOVE_USER_TOKENS_SQL = "delete from " + DEF_TABLE_SQL + " where username = ?";

    // ~ Instance fields
    // ================================================================================================

    private String tokensBySeriesSql = DEF_TOKEN_BY_SERIES_SQL;
    private String insertTokenSql = DEF_INSERT_TOKEN_SQL;
    private String updateTokenSql = DEF_UPDATE_TOKEN_SQL;
    private String removeUserTokensSql = DEF_REMOVE_USER_TOKENS_SQL;
    private boolean createTableOnStartup;

    protected void initDao() {
        if (createTableOnStartup) {
            getJdbcTemplate().execute(CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
        }
    }

    public void createNewToken(PersistentRememberMeToken token) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update(insertTokenSql, token.getUsername(), token.getSeries(),
                token.getTokenValue(), token.getDate());
    }

    public void updateToken(String series, String tokenValue, Date lastUsed) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update(updateTokenSql, tokenValue, lastUsed, series);
    }

    public PersistentRememberMeToken getTokenForSeries(String seriesId) {
        try {
            return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(tokensBySeriesSql,
                    new RowMapper<PersistentRememberMeToken>() {
                        public PersistentRememberMeToken mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                                throws SQLException {
                            return new PersistentRememberMeToken(rs.getString(1), rs
                                    .getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getTimestamp(4));
                        }
                    }, seriesId);
        }
        catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException zeroResults) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Querying token for series '" + seriesId
                        + "' returned no results.", zeroResults);
            }
        }
        catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException moreThanOne) {
            logger.error("Querying token for series '" + seriesId
                    + "' returned more than one value. Series" + " should be unique");
        }
        catch (DataAccessException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to load token for series " + seriesId, e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void removeUserTokens(String username) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update(removeUserTokensSql, username);
    }

    public void setCreateTableOnStartup(boolean createTableOnStartup) {
        this.createTableOnStartup = createTableOnStartup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that won't work since there's no such thing as "overriding variables" (not to be confused with variable hiding), especially for constants like in this case.

However since `JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl` is a small class, it is possible to extend it (or implement `PersistentTokenRepository`), copy the full implementation then rewrite the necessary parts (which is basically all of it) to use your own queries.

That's the easiest way. `JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl` doesn't provide any support for configuring anything, so the best you can do is copy-paste it as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you. So I downloaded source code from here: [link]https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.java 

And added parameter for SQL tables (see the code attached above).
Is it optimal way? I'm afraid that in further changes of this library It won't work...

Comment: @coder999 well, since you're not using any of the superclass functionality (except through copy-pasting) I would only implement `PersistentTokenRepository` (and you don't need to re-implement it if you extend `JTRI`). Then just configure your class to be used as the implementation. It can't break anything since you've implemented the interface correctly.